# how can I bind a class member function with param as rvalue to boost::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I try to bind a class member function with param as rval to boost::function.
But it doesn't work.
my sample false code :

```
class Class1
{
    int Foo1(int&& b)
    {
        return b;
    }   

    void foo2()
    {
        boost::function<int(int&&)> fc(boost::bind(&Class1::Foo1, this, _1) 
    }   
};
```

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. For example http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda expression:

```
boost::function<int(int&&)> fc = [this](int&& x)
{
    return Foo1(x);
};
```